# How to "cast" python type hints

Tags: python, types

I have a client library which has a function that looks like this

```
def connect(timeout: float):
```

However, the documentation for that client states that if `timeout` is not specified or None it will effectively use the default timeout.  I've tested that that is the case, and it works properly specifying the value of `None` for `timeout`

My code then wraps this connect method with something like:

```
def my_connect(timeout: float = None):
    connect(timeout=timeout)
```

When I run mypy against that to validate the type hinting, it complains that: the argument `timeout` to `connect` was expecting `float` but got `Optional[float]`.

I would rather not have to have additional logic in my code to change the way I'm calling the `connect` method based on if the default value of `None` was used in the `my_connect` method, as that would require additional unit tests, and the entire reason I needed the timeout in the first place was because the unit tests would block without the timeout on a negative test-case.

What is the recommended way of handling this?  Is there some way to force the parameter to be accepted even though the library creator explicitly specified a non-optional float?  The library is proprietary and binary-only, so I don't have the ability to change the signature, and I'd really like to try to make this work without having to change any functional logic, only type hinting.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if your client library accepts `None`, then it should be typed as `Optional[float]`, are you creating these stubs?

Comment: Type hint are hints and no static typing. Python remains a duck typed language. Your desire to enforce static typing in a language that is designed for dynamic typing is what has created your problem.

Comment: Do you have the ability to define the default timeout in your wrapper? If so, you could call `connect(timeout=timeout or DEFAULT)`.

Comment: I agree, the client should have been typed as `Optional[float]` instead of just `float`, but like I said, it's a proprietary binary library, and I don't have access to the source to fix that.

Comment: @KlausD. your comment is not that helpful.  I don't have a desire to enforce anything. The project I'm working on, uses type hinting as a means of checking consistency when the code is pushed through our CI department.  I don't have the say as to if and where we do type hinting, but I have to comply with my company's internal requirements. At least I do like that Python allows type hinting without enforcing strict types on things.  It's much more helpful than hurtful.

Comment: @CarlosMermingas, I'm not sure that would solve the problem, as `timeout` in the wrapping function's scope is typed as `Optional[float]` because of the default `None`, and that would still result in getting flagged for passing an optional float (even though with the condition, it would never be `None`).  However, it might be acceptable to change the default in the `my_connect` method from `None` to `DEFAULT`, in which case, it would imply the explicit type of `float` which may pass the check.

Comment: Right... My point was that *you* define a default in your wrapper. I just called it `DEFAULT`. Whether you put it in your wrapper's signature or in the body depends on how you get that default (e.g. is it statically defined or dynamically loaded?). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution to this, which seems to pass all checks, and seems functionally equivalent.

Again, the library signature was

```
def connect(timeout: float):
```

And the wrapper was:

```
def my_connect(timeout: float = None):
```

As it turns out, the `connect` method, defaulted to `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` if the value was either missing or `None`.  Which was right in the documentation, and I just missed that.

The solution was to simply change the default on the wrapper to use the same `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` instead of None.

e.g.

```
import socket
...
def my_connect(timeout: float = socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
```

This causes the implicit type hinting of converting `float` to `Optional[float]` if the value is explicitly `None` to not occur, which correctly types the argument as `float`.  That allows the type hint checks to completely pass.